# Why is port 1111 open, and is it safe to be?

Tags: linux, networking, security, port, tcp

I'm new to systems administration and have a server running a website with HTTP (at port 80), HTTPS (at port 443) and SSH (at port 22).

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04.

I did an Nmap port scan using my personal laptop and other than these 3 ports, port 1111 was open too. This was the output:

```
1111/tcp open tcpwrapped
```

I then did:

```
sudo netstat -lntp | grep -F 1111
```

...and got the following output:

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:1111 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 21596/monit
```

Monit appears to be a monitoring tool in Ubuntu.

- Should I be concerned about this?
- How do I determine the purpose of port 1111?
- How do I close it if I need to?

Comment: If nmap reports "tcpwrapped," you might also take a look in /etc/hosts.allow or /etc/hosts.deny to see what service is actually being wrapped.

Comment: I am on Linux. Ill update the post to add this.

Comment: @CodeGnome I checked these files and they are both empty (everything in them is commented out information on how to use this file).

Comment: [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) home page.

Comment: I am contacting my hosting service to check if they did something to enable this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this reference:](http://www.auditmypc.com/tcp-port-1111.asp)

> Because protocol TCP port 1111 was flagged as a virus (colored red)
>   does not mean that a virus is using port 1111, but that a Trojan or
>   Virus has used this port in the past to communicate.

So, it could be a virus/trojan.

I would recommend you to use [Net Activity Viewer](http://netactview.sourceforge.net/) to determine what process/service is keeping this port on listening state:

[image]

After this, Google the process name to see if there are any viruses related to this process and to this port.

Finally, if you think it is a virus, just follow the [instructions guided here.](https://superuser.com/q/100360/79358)

Comment: I am on a linux machine. Is a `sudo netstat -lntp | fgrep 1111` equivalent of this?

Comment: @Nikunj Edited to Linux TCP View program. Probably netstat can't list prot related to processes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Diogo. Is there a CLI thing that helps me do this? I do not have a ubuntu gui install on my server

Comment: looks like iftop and iptraf are alternatives on the cmd line.

Comment: Try this guide: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/

Comment: That guide is amazing. Will keep updating with findings. I am also contacting the hosting service to see if they are using it for anything.

Comment: I think the information quoted from the first reference is meaningless.  With only 64k ports available total, I suspect that most if not all ports have been used by at least on virus regardless of if whoever is maintaining that list has seen one that does it.

Comment: Moved to comment from the OP, nknj: I finally ended on contacting my hosting service provider, rackspace, and they were using this service to monitor the systems health using a tool called monit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lsof -i :1111` to find the process connected to port 1111.

Answer (score 2):

IANA's (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority) port description is:

> 1111  tcp,udp lmsocialserver  LM Social Server

But its also known to be used by

```
1111    tcp trojan  Daodan, Ultors Trojan   Trojans
1111    udp trojan  Daodan  Trojans
1111    tcp threat  W32.Suclove Bekkoame
1111    tcp,udp threat  AIMVision   Bekkoame

Trojans that use this port:
    Backdoor.AIMvision - remote access trojan, 10.2002. Affects all current Windows versions.
    Backdoor.Ultor - remote access trojan, 06.2002. Affects Windows, listens on port 1111 or 1234.
    Backdoor.Daodan - VB6 remote access trojan, 07.2000. Affects Windows.
    W32.Suclove.A@mm (09.26.2005) - a mass-mailing worm with backdoor capabilities that spreads through MS Outlook and MIRC. Opens a backdoor and listens for remote commands on port 1111/tcp.
```

Sources:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml

http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=1111

Answer (score 2):

#### Check /etc/services

Generally, you can find standard service ports listed in */etc/services*. However, on my system:

```
fgrep 1111 /etc/services
```

returns no information, so it's probably not a standard service.

#### Check netstat

You can see what programs are using a given port with *netstat*.

```
sudo netstat -lntp | fgrep 1111
```

You can then use that information to determine if it's a necessary system service for your environment.

#### Stopping Unnecessary Processes

Stopping system processes is somewhat platform-specific, but many Linux systems support a `sudo service ssh stop` or similar command, or you can call the startup script directly with `sudo /etc/init.d/<service> stop`. If it's not a system service, you can just call `sudo kill <pid>` to send SIGTERM to the process.

Note that stopping a service doesn't prevent it from running again, so you may also need to adjust your runlevel startup scripts in whatever way is appropriate for your specific platform.

Comment: Thanks for this. `fgrep 1111 /etc/service` gave no info.
`sudo netstat -lntp | fgrep 1111` however gave this output:
`tcp    0    0 0.0.0.0:1111    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   21596/monit`

Comment: Use `grep -F` instead of `fgrep`. Quote from `man grep`: *Direct invocation […] is deprecated, but is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified.*

Comment: Thanks @Marco. This still gives the same output. Any idea whats going on? Is this a virus?

Answer (score 1):

This [speedguide.net](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=1111) page indicates that TCP port 1111 is used by an app called LikeMinds Socialserver, but it also says it's known to be used by several malware apps.  Perhaps a full malware scan of your disk is in order.

Answer (score 1):

From `aptitude show monit`:

```
Description: utility for monitoring and managing daemons or similar programs
monit is a utility for monitoring and managing daemons or similar programs running on a 
Unix system. It will start specified
programs if they are not running and restart programs not responding.
```

If you don't plan to use it you should uninstall it or at least stop it and prevent automatic start with

```
/etc/init.d/monit stop
update-rc.d -f monit remove
```

Or you can [learn to use it](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/) and configure it to your needs.